# Storyboard viewcontroller's custom class set as a viewcontroller without xib shows black

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm in the middle of updating our app to start using storyboards. 
I have a ViewController in my storyboard with a custom class. The custom class points to a ViewController without a nib. However its parent class does have a nib. This ends up as a black screen in the device. Even if I remove most of the code.

If I instead use the parent class in the storyboard it loads fine. It is like the storyboard can't locate the nib for the child class.

Anyone know what the problem is?

[image]

Comment: You can't create a ViewController in Storyboard which is a subclass of a ViewController which id loaded with a nib. That would be 2 interface files (nib + storyboard) for one ViewController.

Comment: Oh really? Bugger. In that case put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a ViewController in Storyboard which is a subclass of a ViewController which is loaded with a nib. That would be 2 interface files (nib + storyboard) for one ViewController.

Comment: Is there a page where Apple discusses this?